# 404 Error Due to Head request from Bot

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404, web-crawler

I have a Node.js app running Express.js.  The site works fine when requesting:  https://mysite.com/ from a browser.

I setup a catch all 404 and log what URL was requested (to see where users are getting confused, etc.). However, I keep getting a 404 log message with the URL https://mysite.com/

Here are more details on the user agent that triggers this:

req.headers[user-agent]: "Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.17.0-rc (gzip)"
req.route.method : "head"

I think its a Bot requesting a "head" only instead of a "get".  Why would a bot do a head request?  Should I fix this by allowing responses in express from both head and get?

Comment: Bots use HEAD requests to sniff around your domain without prompting your server to send response bodies, just headers.  Saves bandwidth that way, and the bot still gets a clear idea of the structure of your site.  Can you post the relevant sections of your app? I threw together a small app and made some GET and HEAD requests against it, and I can't reproduce.

Comment: Also, here's the HTTP spec, where HEAD is explained. 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: If the HEAD returns 404 is that perceived as bad?

Comment: Well, if you're interested in Google effectively indexing the site you've built (thereby making it searchable), then yeah.  If you don't care, then nah. Depends on what the point of your app/site is.